# how can i read the screen width and height in android?

Tags: javascript, android, html, css

I am trying to read the screen width and height using the fallowing code:

```
var height;
var width;
var w = window;
var d = document;
var e = d.documentElement;
var g = d.getElementsByTagName('body')[0];

width = w.innerWidth || e.clientWidth || g.clientWidth;
height = w.innerHeight || e.clientHeight || g.clientHeight;
```

that code is called by an "onload" event. It works fine on apple devices but on android, 9 out of 10 times i get a 0 in for the width and a wrong height.

Can anyone please help?

Comment: Make sure your web-page starts with an appropriate DOCTYPE tag, so that mobile browser does not fall into compatibility mode.

Answer (score 1):

Here it is

```
DisplayMetrics metrics = context.getResources().getDisplayMetrics();
int width = metrics.widthPixels;
int height = metrics.heightPixels;
```

Comment: This link may also help you out

http://www.ilovecolors.com.ar/detect-screen-size-css-style/

Comment: The question is about JavaScript in Android, not about Java code.

Answer (score 0):

Using this code you can get runtime Display's Width & Height

```
DisplayMetrics displaymetrics = new DisplayMetrics();
getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(displaymetrics);
int height = displaymetrics.heightPixels;
int width = displaymetrics.widthPixels;
```